# React-Syncfusion-RadioButton opttional value vs required

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, radio-button, syncfusion

I would like to have the yes radiobutton to be optional and not to required the comments. This is what I have . what would it be the easiest way to have this value optional and leave the NO radiobutton as it is ?

```
 <Field
        component={RadioGroup}
        name="result"
        required={true}
        options={[
          { title: 'Yes', value: 'yes'},
          { title: 'No', value: 'no' },
        ]}
      />
      </div>
      </div>
      <hr className="hr-line" />
      <div className="txt-area">
      <Field
        name="comments"
        type="text"
        component={renderTextField}
        label="Enter Comments Here"
        validate={[required]}
      />
      </div>
      <hr className="hr-line" />
      <div className="d-flex flex-row-reverse ">     
        <Button type="submit" className="btn-group w-25" size="sm" color="primary" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Save Changes</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have checked with the provided code and noticed that Syncfusion Components were not used over here. The functionalities provided in the default Radio Button is also available with our Syncfusion Components.

Refer to the below links to know more about Radio Button component.

Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/button/radio-button

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/radio-button/getting-started/

API: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/radio-button/

Please check with the above links and provide us an example based upon your requirement. We have also attached a sample here for your reference.

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/RadioButton1391065099

Please get back to us if you need further assistance.

Regards,

Keerthana.